# How to loop through records and create multiple WordCloud charts?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, word-cloud

I have a simple dataframe with two columns of text. Here is my script.

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
for i in df_cat.columns:
    text = df_cat[i].values
    wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(str(text))
    plt.imshow(wordcloud)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
```

Here's the two WordClouds that I get.

[image]

I am trying to figure out how to modify this code, or do something totally different, so I can generate a WordCloud based on the dataframe shown below.

```
import pandas as pd
  
# intialise data of lists.
data = {'MyTExt':['MainOutage', 'MainOutage', 'Bills', 'Bills', 'Payments', 'Payments', 'Menu', 'Menu', 'Menu'],
        'Duration':[200, 200, 400, 500, 20, 40, 50, 50, 60],
        'Bin':['(23.6, 771.0]', '(23.6, 771.0]', '(23.6, 771.0]', '(23.6, 771.0]', '(771.0, 1511.0]', '(771.0, 1511.0]', '(771.0, 1511.0]', '(771.0, 1511.0]', '(771.0, 1511.0]']}
  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

[image]

So, instead of having multiple columns with text, I have a single column with text, and I'm trying to generate a WordCloud per Duration or per Bin. I tried to pivot the data, but I couldn't get it to work? Is this doable?